# Facebook Insights error

Tags: html, facebook, metadata

I have tried to setup Facebook insights for a customers website (http://www.luof.co.uk). However, when I try to set it up, it comes up with this

The app ID "343,046,272,445,393" specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag was invalid

I have matched it up to the source code, and the IDs are exactly the same. Any ideas?

Comment: you have matched it up to what source code? you need to insert the app ID that belongs to the fb:app you create.

Comment: yeah I have done that, I matched the app ID to the meta tag in the sites' source code; yet it won't work for some reason.